# asp.net DetailsView allowing ID / PK entry

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a DetailsView which is defaulted to insert mode:

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource"
    AutoGenerateInsertButton="true" DefaultMode="Insert"
    DataKeyNames="ID"></asp:DetailsView>
```

The issue being that the input for `ID` is editable, i.e. a user can input an ID. Entering an ID does nothing on the actual update command, but a user shouldn't think he can put their own ID in the first place. I don't have `ID` as an `InputParameter` nor is it included in the actual SQL command in the code-behind.

On a `GridView` that uses the same `SqlDataSource`, I easily disabled ID editing using the `DataKeyNames="ID"` attribute but this doesn't seem to have worked for the `DetailsView` - any ideas how to prevent a user editing the ID field?

---

**EDIT:**
I've just added an ID attribute, `AutoGenerateRows="true"` and `EnableModelValidation="true"` and still nothing preventing user from toying with the ID field.

Comment: Is the ID field you added named "ID", or is it something else like "CustomerID"? That would cause the control not to recognize the DataKeyName.

Comment: It's definitely just `ID` and it works fine with GridView, just not DetailsView.

Comment: Nah, it's definitely `ID` and it works fine for a GridView row that has the same SqlDataSource with the same DataKeyNames="ID"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from Microsoft Help:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="CustomerDetail" 
        DataSourceID="Details" AutoGenerateRows="false"
        AutoGenerateInsertButton="true" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
        EmptyDataText="No records." 
        DataKeyNames="CustomerID" GridLines="Both" 
        OnItemInserted="CustomerDetail_ItemInserted"
        OnItemInserting="CustomerDetail_ItemInserting" 
        OnItemUpdated="CustomerDetail_ItemUpdated"
        OnItemUpdating="CustomerDetail_ItemUpdating" 
        OnItemDeleted="CustomerDetail_ItemDeleted"
        runat="server">
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Navy" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="LightCyan" />
        <Fields>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" />
        </Fields>
      </asp:DetailsView>
```

Note under <Fields>, the first field has a `ReadOnly="True"` attribute. Try that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the aim was to use the autoGeneratedColumns so I shouldn't have to specify the ReadOnly, that should be inferred form the DataKeyNames - or so I thought, maybe it only works with GridView and not with DetailsView